# JSONObject JSON array length

Tags: java, xml, json

I am reading the below XML in java, and converting to `JSONObject` [`org.json.JSONObject`].
and appending the metadata and returning as JSON.

**Problem**: 
`JSONObject jsonObj = service.getMyData();` // custom methods and invocation

`int count = jsonObj.length();` // length is 1

How do I take the correct count from this jsonObj? . The correct count I am referring to is 2 in this case. [2 books]

What I tried?

(1) `System.out.println(jsonObj.length());` // prints 1

API says: length() 
          Get the number of keys stored in the JSONObject.

(2) Since number of keys is returned as 1, there is no point on trying the below one, still I tried 
 and got the error of `org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["User"] not found.`

```
 System.out.println(jsonObj.getJSONArray("User").length());
```

(3) IF I try 'Users' ie: `jsonObj.getJSONArray("Users").length()` , it says `JSONObject["Users"] is not a JSONArray`.

(4)

```
JSONObject jsonObj = service.getMyData();
 JSONObject jUsers =  jsonObj.getJSONObject("Users");
 JSONObject jUser =  jUsers.getJSONObject("User");
 System.out.println(jUser.length());
```

Error: `org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["User"] is not a JSONObject.`

---

**XML:**

```
<Users>
    <User>
        <Name>Unni</Name>
        <Books>
            <Book>book1</Book>
            <Book>book2</Book>
            <Book>book3</Book>
        </Books>
    </User>
    <User>
        <Name>Ammu</Name>
        <Books>
            <Book>book1</Book>
            <Book>book2</Book>
            <Book>book4</Book>
        </Books>
    </User>
</Users>
```

**JSON:**

```
{
    "Users": {
        "User": [
            {
                "Name": "Unni",
                "Books": {
                    "Book": [
                        "book1",
                        "book2",
                        "book3"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "Ammu",
                "Books": {
                    "Book": [
                        "book1",
                        "book2",
                        "book4"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You posted the question and answer together? If you want to share your work in figuring this out, you should create an answer. I just wasted time trying to help you

Comment: In the JSON you've posted, `Users` is a `JSONObject` and `User` is a `JSONArray`.

Comment: @crush The OP already knows the answer, look for **Solution** in the question

Comment: my bad! I posted as answer

Comment: I am sorry for your time @JuanMendes, Thanks for trying

Comment: @prash Next time, look for the checkbox "Answer your own question" so your question won't be without an answer since others will try to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `JSON` format,

`[]` is JSONArray

`{}` is JSONObject

In your post,

- **Users** - JSONObject
- **User** - JSONArray
- **Books** - JSONObject
- **Book** - JSONArray

---

```
Error: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["User"] is not a JSONObject.
```

As mentioned above, try with `getJSONArray()`

```
 JSONArray userArray = jUsers.getJSONArray("User");
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to call the `getJSONArray` method when retrieving the array.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = service.getMyData();
JSONObject jUsers =  jsonObj.getJSONObject("Users");
System.out.println(jUsers.getJSONArray("User").length());
```